# How to use c++ classes without names?

Tags: c++, class

I encountered a problem in opensource c++ code. The following is a small and simplified version to describe my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define TOGETHER2(a,b) a ## b
#define TOGETHER(a,b) TOGETHER2(a,b)
#define GENERATE_NAME(a) TOGETHER(a,__COUNTER__)
#define GENERATE     GENERATE_NAME(__seed_)
class base{
}b;

class GENERATE:public base{
}GENERATE;

class GENERATE:public base{
}GENERATE;

class GENERATE:public base{
}GENERATE;

class GENERATE:public base{
}GENERATE;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

As we can see, the author defines several classes, which inherites a base class. But the author do not care about the names of the classes. So I wonder **how can I use those classes without specifying their names?**

**Is this a kind of design pattern in c++ that I don't know?**

Thank you :)

---

I want to add my guesses to make the question clear.

---

My guesses:

The names of these classes are generated from __seed_, but when I search through the files, I can not find other references to __seed_, So I am sure The author did not use the names __seed_1, __seed_2 to create classes. (Actually the author said the the comments that she did not care about the names of the classes)

I also guessed that the author may have used those classes through the interface defined in the base class(virtual function). To do that, the author still needed to create these classes, but as I mentioned I could not find __seed_ in other parts of the code, So the author couldn't create classes, and therefore virtual function do not work either.

Actually, I tried remove these class definitions, and strangely the code compiles correctly. However, It lost some of functionalities, but It did not just core dump. It could still finish some tasks successfully *u*

So, do anyone know:

- How can we use those classes without specifying their names?
- Is this design a certain kind of design pattern?
- In which situation should we define class without caring about their names?
- As I mentioned, I removed some part of the code, and It compiled. How could this happen? I mean, Since I remove many classes from the source code, then If other parts of the code references those classes, the source can not compile. And If it compiles, Can I just conclude that those classes are not needed?

ADDED:
As some of you recommended, 
the full source code is here: [MIT Cryptdb](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb/blob/master/main/rewrite_const.cc). In the file ./main/rewrite_const.cc, the author used macro ANON(lion 25) to define many classes without caring about their names.

Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: It's probably an attempt at stopping users of this library from instantiating the class by themselves, and/or keeping the executable's symbol table obfuscated. There should be some mechanism in place to get instances (by some enum or string).

Comment: If it's open source could you please share the link to the full base? It could help figuring out what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps the reason for generating classes like this is to do something different during static initialization of each class (registering a single object of the same class or a class factory I think is a fairly common scenario).  __COUNTER__ could  even be auto-generated,by a build script that compiles the same file over and over with different values for __COUNTER__ and specifying a different object file name each time. Was this pattern found in some unit test framework ?

Comment: Apparently "__COUNTER__" is a micorosft preprocessor extension.

Comment: Hi, The Vee, I edit my question and add the link :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to edit the code and add names for the classes. This is a strange design pattern, and I wouldn't recommend you to use such pattern for anything, unless you want to prevent others from using your classes.

If the author wants you to use those classes, there is probably some way you can use them without editing the code and adding the names. You should consult the documentation for this.

> As I mentioned, I removed some part of the code, and It compiled. How could this happen? I mean, Since I remove many classes from the source code, then If other parts of the code references those classes, the source can not compile. And If it compiles, Can I just conclude that those classes are not needed?

All those generated classes are derived from the base class. So if you remove one class, all classes that come after it receive a new generated name. If the code now compiles, it means the other code is only calling the methods that are part of the base class. But the other code is now using other classes than what it originally used, which causes the errors you observe.

Consider this:

- Initially the generated classes have names A, B, and C.
- You remove class A.
- Now the generated classes have names A and B. Class named C no longer exists, so the code that uses it should no longer compile. And the code that used class A and B before, it is now using the classes that used to be B and C.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer provides a new perspective for me :)

Answer (score 3):

**These classes do have names.** Only that these names are not revealed to the human reader and are not specified before the preprocessor has run. (If you run the compiler with option `-E`, it will only run the preprocessor stage and output the code as the compiler proper sees it, including the class names.)

AFAIK, there is no sensible reason to hide the names in this way. If the author doesn't want humans to write code that uses these classes, then there are other ways.

Defining such names in a header file to be included by the user implies that they cannot be used from within the library other than via polymorphism (because the library cannot know their names). This is the reason why removing them made no difference regarding compilation.